# MySQL vs MariaDB: add row number

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a SQL like this:

```
select a.*, (@r := @r+1) as seq
from (
    ....
    order by xx asc
) as a
join (select @r:=0) as y
```

I used to use MySQL, and this SQL ran just fine.
Unfortunately, when I migrate to MariaDB,
this SQL produces wierd results.
The results aren't in the correct order.
The "`order by`" clause seems to be ignored...

Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard says it is OK.  [*More Info*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/).

One solution (as mentioned above) is to set `optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'`.